# Jest: Files names without .test or .spec in them

Tags: jestjs

I'm migrating from Mocha/Chai to Jest, and I have a lot of test files. The file names are in the format `componentTest.js` and are all in subdirectories of `/test`. Jest doesn't seem to like that. Running `jest /test` doesn't find anything. Running `jest /test/components/componentTest.js` also says no tests found. Changing the `/test` director name doesn't work either. It's only when I change the name of the file to `component.test.js` that it finds the tests, but that's not going to work for my case without a script. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Jest will find any tests that are located inside a `__tests__` folder as well.

And then to run your tests, just run: `jest`